# Installation of TextBlob in python 3.9.7

Tags: python, textblob

please excuse my question, I am a total beginner.
I want to use TextBlob in python to perform a sentiment analysis on german Twitter data. Everything seems to work so far, except the downloads/updates of nltk corpora and language models used in TextBlob (right at the beginning when installing TextBlob).

```
pip install -U textblob-de
```

This works just fine and pip show textblob-de shows that Version: 0.4.3 is installed.

The second line (python -m textblob.download_corpora) downloads/updates nltk corpora and language models used in TextBlob.

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

But here I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\imken\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1596/1059265410.py", line 3
    python -m textblob.download_corpora
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea where the error comes from and many searches on the internet did not get me anywhere so far. I work in Jupyter Notebook and have also tried the download of the nltk packages in Colaboratory, but it doesn't seem to work. I have imported nltk already.

If anyone could help me I would be really grateful! Thank you a lot in advance!